# While importing tensorflow, got the error 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.'

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, compiler-errors

I have seen and implemented several potential solutions to my problem, but none seem to work.
Can I get resolution for the error in importing tensorflow?

**Versions**
-- > python 3.7.4
-- > tensorflow 2.3.0

```
runfile('C:/Users/pshad/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/pshad/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-bc8fb4f78acd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/pshad/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/pshad/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/pshad/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\pshad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda offers an installation for Tensorflow that takes care of everything, including all the GPU and CUDA dependencies:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

It's for Tensorflow 2.1 and Python 3.7. DLL failures are common when components are installed separately or through another channel than Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I think the package didn't installed correctly. try reinstalling it.(if you use 'pip' to install don't forget to update it)

Comment: I have tried that several times, upgrading, downgrading, uninstalling and reinstalling. Nothing seem to work

Comment: I suggest you to try programming in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com). this is faster and does'nt need to install any library too

Comment: Thanks but Google services are not allowed in China.

Comment: @MohammadSadraSharifzadeh does it mean I can also run computationally complex and time consuming codes as well using Google Colab?

Comment: yes it mean! but it's usually used for running AI programs(specially tensor-flow)